# Obtain best feasible solution with SCIP

Tags: scip

I am using [SCIP (SoPlex)](http://scip.zib.de/) to solve a MIP (mixed integer program) provided by a .mps file. I use SCIP via command line as follows:

```
SCIP> read file.mps
original problem has 1049 variables (471 bin, 0 int, 0 impl, 578 cont) and 638 constraints
SCIP> optimize    # so i am using default settings
... some solving information ...
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 0.46
Solving Nodes      : 1
Primal Bound       : -6.58117502066443e+05 (2 solutions)
Dual Bound         : -6.58117502066443e+05
Gap                : 0.00 %
[linear] c_2_141>: x_2_73_141[C] - 1000000000 y_2_141[B] <= 0;
violation: right hand side is violated by 236.775818639799
best solution is not feasible in original problem
```

I do not want to have an infeasible solution – a want the best feasible. For your information: I used CPLEX with the same file and it confirmed that there is an optimal feasible solution with slightly worse obj value (like 0.05 % worse).
I already tried to put emphasis on feasibility with `SCIP> set emphasis feasibility` but that did not help me – see for yourself:

```
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 0.42
Solving Nodes      : 3 (total of 5 nodes in 3 runs)
Primal Bound       : -6.58117502066443e+05 (4 solutions)
Dual Bound         : -6.58117502066443e+05
Gap                : 0.00 %
[linear] c_2_141>: x_2_73_141[C] - 1000000000 y_2_141[B] <= 0;
violation: right hand side is violated by 236.775818639799
best solution is not feasible in original problem
```

Kind regards.

EDIT:
In response to the answer of user mattmilten, I have to share that using `set numerics feastol 1e-9` alone did not bring a feasible solution, but using a lower tolerance like `1e-10` **in combination** with `set emphasis feasibility`, SCIP is able to provide a good feasible solution that is just 0.005 % worse than CPLEX’.

Thanks for your help mattmilten!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to tighten the tolerances, especially the feasibility tolerance:

```
set numerics feastol 1e-9
```

The violated constraint contains a very large coefficient. This is likely the cause for this high absolute error. In CPLEX you should also try

```
display solution quality
```

to check whether the solution found by CPLEX is also violating the bounds.

Comment: You might also try to disable scaling/presolving within SoPlex. Or disabling SCIPs presolving.

Comment: Could you please upload your problematic instance somewhere so that I can have a look myself?

Comment: See my edit for new information. Sorry for the late reply but at least I found a solution with your help.
Anyway: how could I change parameters of SoPlex using SCIP?

Comment: You can change some parameters of SoPlex using SCIP. Have a look at the options provided with `set/lp` from within the interactive shell